# How to show current data of DataGridView in report of stimulSoftReport

Tags: c#, datagridview, stimulsoft

I have a form in which there is a search button and a DataGridView. When I click on search button, the data of DataGridView may change.

Now I want show this data in a report of stimulSoftReport by clicking on print button.

I use this code in click event of print button (I don't know it is correct or not):

```
DataTable dt = dgvAccounting.DataSource as DataTable;

strAccounting.RegData(dt);
strAccounting.Show();
```

but I don't know what I should do in report design environment.

Answer (score 1):

You need create a report with your datasource - place a DataBand component with necessary text. And then use your code for show the report.

You can find many videos by the following link:
http://www.stimulsoft.com/en/videos?tags=quickstart